# Problem with Facebook Comments on AMP Pages

Tags: facebook-comments

I am writing to you because I tried to insert Facebook comments in [THIS AMP PAGE](https://synapticweb.it/2019/12/13/come-aumentare-i-like-della-tua-pagina-facebook-4-errori-da-evitare/amp/), but it does not work. It's a Wordpress site built by Pennews Theme.

Following [THIS GUIDE](https://amp.dev/it/documentation/components/amp-facebook-comments/?format=websites), I entered this code:

```
<script async="" custom-element="amp-facebook-comments" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-facebook-comments-0.1.js"></script>
```

inside Header (Rather, from Customize AMP> Header Options, I inserted this script inside the Header field ....),**because in this theme it's can't insert any code in tag Head on AMP pages**, but just in tag header...
  and this other code:

```
<amp-facebook-comments width="486" height="657" layout="responsive" date-numposts="5" data-href="https://synapticweb.it/2019/12/13/come-aumentare-i-like-della-tua-pagina-facebook-4-errori-da-evitare/amp">
```

in an html element inside the body of the page ..

But I have these problems:

1) The comment is not displayed.

2) As you can see from [THIS VIDEO](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TDZp9ldDl2E_jPgzsC8wI94tSKdc22MI/view), the page loads, but you don't see the icons ..., you can check better from the attachment.

3) This AMP page is not validated by the [TEST](https://search.google.com/test/amp?utm_source=gws&utm_medium=onebox&utm_campaign=suit&id=bRWJHRNkYfp9yOqPlScfvw)

Thanks a lot!

> > > > How can I solve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpgyQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

resolve js errors on page. Facebook comments loaded by javascript but if js error occur on page it fail
[image]